# Generate a unique numeric value for a string

Tags: algorithm

I have a number of unique strings (dictionary words) and I would like to generate a unique numeric value for each string.  The requirement is that the same string should always map to the same numeric value.

What's the best way to generate the unique id?

Comment: *Huge* array? Let's say your dictionary contains 1 *million* words and the average length is *20* characters. So, by storing those in a ahem Dictionary class (C#/java (hint hint)), you'll be using 20 megabytes of memory. Whoopdee doo. A rasberry pi has 256 MB of ram. I *really* wouldn't worry about memory at this point if I were you. Throw it into a Dictionary/hashtable/hashset and call it a day.

Comment: Clang is throwing fit with a big dictionary.

Comment: Found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852334/algorithm-that-generates-unique-serial-number-for-each-english-word?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of [Hashing?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) This is exactly what it's meant for. If you use a decent hash you should see unique numbers. This is actually how dictionaries check that the "index" is valid.

Comment: Hashing can still collide.  I need a 100% safe way.

Comment: @Boon the chance of a good hash colliding is near 0. Git uses a hash function to store most objects and even attempts at forcing a clash have so far failed.

Comment: Understood, but I can't do near zero, it has to be zero.